# jQuery fadeIn() not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-animate, fadein

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 //Default Action
 $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
 $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
 $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

 //On Click Event
 $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
  $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
  $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
  var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
  $(activeTab).fadeIn("slow"); //Fade in the active content
  return false;
 });

});
```

Works in everything but IE?

Comment: instead of return false you should use preventDefault()

Comment: Hmm. I wouldn't expect anything involving alpha blending to work properly in IE, but maybe that's just because of how badly it used to support PNGs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to get consistent behavior:

```
var activeTab = $(this).find("a").get(0).hash;
```

IE likes to return not `"#id"` but instead it thinks you want:  `"http://site.com/currentPage.html#id"`, which won't work for a selector :)  I you grab the `.hash` off the DOM element, you get just he `#id` portion consistently.

[You can find a bit more discussion on *why* this happens in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342903/jquery-not-parsing-properly-attrhref-in-ie)

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).find("a").attr("href")` gets you the HREF of the target, not the target. Assuming you're putting the name of a DIV in the href in there that may be correct (I don't know what's in there).

Try `alert($(this).find("a").href())` to see if you've got the right element, or just try `.show()` and see what happens.