# iframe created with jquery prepends absolute URL with current domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, xss

I am creating an iframe using jQuery to a "cross-site" URL. This works properly in Firefox but IE is prepending the parent pages domain to the iframes src URL.

An example would be if I am creating the iframe (with jQuery):

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

The page that IE would try to load is:

```
http://www._mysite_.com/http://www.google.com
```

If I statically in the HTML create the iframe everything works fine. It is only when I make it using JS that it loads the wrong page.

I suppose I would understand if this was intentional cross-site protection that IE has built in, but I am wondering if that is the case, or if I am missing something.

Is this default behavior for IE? If anyone has a workaround it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Generated code is:

```
<iframe id="myIframe" width="500" height="400" frameborder="0" src="http://www._website_.com/aaa/bbb/ccc">
```

I tested the generated code at static HTML and it did work properly in IE.

EDIT 2:

This is how I am creating the iframe:

```
jQuery('.signUp').live('click', function() {

    var url = 'http://www._website_.com'+$(this).attr('href');

    var thisModal='<div id="dialogRes" class="windowG"><iframe id="iframeG" frameborder="0" width="500" height="400" src="#"></iframe></div>';

    jQuery('body').append(thisModal);

    jQuery('#iframeG').prop('src', url);        

    return false;

});
```

On this line:

```
jQuery('#iframeG').prop('src', url);
```

I have tried `attr()` as well as removing it all together and just putting the `url` in the `src` tag of the iframe. Nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Well, just in case, may we see the generating code?

Comment: No problem I will add it above.

Comment: how do you build this iframe in jQuery

Comment: Added the code above, thanks for checking it out. I realize `live` isn't cool anymore but I am dependent on an older version of jQuery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342903/jquery-not-parsing-properly-attrhref-in-ie

Comment: @Joseph Thank you! I was able to just check out the href with a regex and rewrite to what I needed it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in IE, the `href` attribute is always returned as an absolute URL. So if you had

```
<a id="demo" href="bar/baz">...</a>
```

Then your on your website http://mydomain.com/foo:

```
jQuery('#demo').attr('href') == 'http://mydomain.com/foo/bar/baz';
```

Two options to work around this are to either parse out the (possible) full domain from the `href` attribute, or to use a different custom attribute just to hold the target address/path (eg `data-href`).